# How can I get last object in CollectionView willDisplayCell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, collectionview

How can I detect UICollectionView last visible object in `willDisplayCell`? In UITableView I can do it by using following code:-

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if([indexPath row] == ((NSIndexPath*)[[tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows] lastObject]).row){
    //DO SOMETHING HERE
    }

}
```

Then for **`UICollectionView`**, how can I do this?

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView willDisplayCell:(UICollectionViewCell *)cell forItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    {
      //HOW CAN I DO THIS SAME LIKE TABLEVIEW?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its exactly the same :-

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView willDisplayCell:(UICollectionViewCell *)cell forItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{     
     if([indexPath row] == ((NSIndexPath*)[[collectionView indexPathsForVisibleItems] lastObject]).row){
         //DO SOMETHING HERE
     }       
}
```

Comment: This is not the correct answer since `indexPathsForVisibleItems` returns an unsorted array (see documentation). So you can't be sure that `lastObject` really is the last object.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with `indexPathsForVisibleItems` is that - according to https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview/1618020-indexpathsforvisibleitems?language=objc -  it contains an

> unsorted array of NSIndexPath objects

Therefore you have to use a different approach:

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView willDisplayCell:(UICollectionViewCell *)cell forItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (indexPath.section == collectionView.numberOfSections - 1 && indexPath.row == [collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:collectionView.numberOfSections - 1] - 1) {
        // last row
    } else {
        // "regular" row
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    for (UICollectionViewCell *cell in [self.collection_NewCandidates visibleCells]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.collection_NewCandidates indexPathForCell:cell];
        NSLog(@"your cell index %ld",(long)indexPath.item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Mualik, this will trigger when scroll am i right? what i looking for is without scrolling.